# Making dynamic images have static filenames

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, image, dynamic, seo

My website currently has various  links to a php script that generates the images dynamically.  For example, the link may say "img source="/dynamic_images.php?type=pie-chart&color=red"

Obviously, this is not great for SEO.  I'd like to somehow make the filenames of these links appear to be static, and use a solution (like Mod-Rewrite) to ensure that the images can still be dynamically created.

I suppose I could have something like "img src="average-profits-in-scuba-diving-industry.png?type=pie-chart&color=red" (and use Mod-Rewrite to take care of changing the filename prefix to dynamic_images.php), but I'm afraid that the search engines would shy away from the querystring on the end of the image filename.

Any solutions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You'd need something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^dynamicChart_([^_]+)_([^_]+).png dynamic_images.php?type=$1&color=$2
```

Using the above (if I have written it without typos) should mean that requesting `dynamicChart_pie-chart_red.png` should translate to `dynamic_images.php?type=pie-chart&color=red`

I do not think that the SRC attribute for your images are quite as important to SEO as your ALT or TITLE attributes would be.

Answer (score 2):

You normally use mod_rewrite to hide query strings! You can use file names like these in your pages:

```
/dynamic-images/pie-chart/red/average-profits-in-scuba-diving-industry-19.png
```

And have mod_rewrite translate them to:

```
/dynamic-images.php?type=pie-chart&color=red&datasrc=19
```

Answer (score 0):

For your case use Mod-Rewrite and don't worry about search engines ignoring the query string.

Answer (score 0):

mod_rewrite is one answer, but for something simple like this, it's like nukeing a building to kill a mosquito in one of the rooms. There's `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` available to extract extra path bits, e.g.

```
http://example.com/dynamic-images.php/pie-chart/red/average-profits
```

would have

```
$_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] = '/pie-chart/red/average-profits';
```

which you can then parse with:

```
$query = explode('/', $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']);
```

and you end up with:

```
$query = array(
    0 => '',
    1 => 'pie-chart',
    2 => 'red',
    3 => 'average-profits';
);
```

If you don't want the .php extension exposed in the URL, you can force the web server to treat 'dynamic-images' as a PHP script with an AddHandler directive.